# Присвовение переменной в зависимости от другой переменной

Tags: ansible

Задача при получении значения переменной Service в task "Definition of service" в зависимости от ее значения дописывать путь в task "Detecting the last version of service" в соответствии с зарание определенными значениями в ServiceUp (В ServiceUp записына так же возможные значения Service)

```
vars:
    Service: "{{ TypeOfService }}"
    ServiceUP:
    - { Service: Service.1, ServiceUpSRC: path1 }
    - { Service: Service.2, ServiceUpSRC: path2 }
  tasks:

  - name: Definition of service
    raw: ls /home/user/ | grep Service
    register: TypeOfService
  - debug: msg="{{ TypeOfService.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: Detecting the last version of service
    raw: ls -tl /mnt/r/TypeOfService/{{ item.ServiceUpSRC }}/ | grep Linux | awk '{ print $9, $10, $11 }'| head -1
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    register: version
    with_items:
    - "{{ ServiceUP }}"
  - debug: msg="{{ version.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: У вас регистр разный, `ServiceUp` и `ServiceUP` это разные вещи

Comment: Исправил досадную ошибку с ServiceUP. Данный когда пробегает циклом по заданном в ServiceUP, как его переделать так что б он выбирал из ServiceUP значения в зависимости от результата TypeOfService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот в таком виде должно работать точно, только желательно определить дефолтный путь все-таки.

```
tasks:

  - name: Definition of service
    raw: ls /home/user/ | grep Service
    register: TypeOfService

  - set_fact:
      ServiceUpSRC: path1
    when: TypeOfService == 'Service.1'

  - set_fact: 
      ServiceUpSRC: path2
    when: TypeOfService == 'Service.2'

  - debug: msg="{{ TypeOfService.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: Detecting the last version of service
    raw: ls -tl /mnt/r/TypeOfService/{{ item.ServiceUpSRC }}/ | grep Linux | awk '{ print $9, $10, $11 }'| head -1
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    register: version
    with_items:
    - "{{ ServiceUP }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ version.stdout_lines }}"
```